# Django Image File handling

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have a model `Person`, something like that:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
   first_name = Models.CharField(....)
   last_name = Models.CharField(....)
```

Now, I want to add a user profile image. I have thought about adding the `ImageField` directly or 'wrapping' it in my own custom model and adding a FK to the `Person` model, with the wrapper looking like that:

```py
class MyImageField(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField()
  uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(...)
  description = models.CharText(...)
  owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
  #... other fields for meta data as needed

class Person(models.Model):
   ...
   profile_picture = models.ForeignKey(MyImageField)
```

Would this approach be beneficial? I think, using a custom model has a few benefits:

- More flexibility in terms of storing associated meta data
- Expandable
- Could be kept generic for all usecases where images are needed (User profile, gallery, etc.)
- Single point for encoding filenames, as creating a hash as filename seems better than storing the file under the original name for avoiding duplicate names (as django normally does, as I understand it)
- Possibility of adding an owner property, to allow for easier access control (Check if accessing user is owner, or in the same group or whatever)

Regarding the last part, since images (and files) are stored on the servers file system and not in the database, how would one realize access control from within django? If the image url is known, its easy to guess other image names and therefore get access to the files of other users. Therefore, a request to the image files should need authentication, but I really dont know how to do this in an elegant fashion, but I have found this [package](https://github.com/edoburu/django-private-storage), which could be what I am looking for.

However, I also came up with some drawbacks of this solution:

- Shady in terms of REST access, as one would need a nested write method for adding/editing user profiles.
- I could not find any examples or snippets that use this approach

I suppose I have two questions:

- Is 'wrapping' an ImageField a good idea in general? Would it be good practice to give every model that needs an Image a `ForeignKey` to `MyImage`?
- How would one achieve access control to uploaded files? Ideally this would be possible with [DRF's Permission System](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/), but I don't see how this restricts the serving engine (nginx/Apache) from delivering the image with a direct url (guess).

Comment: For question one, If you want to multiple images or store historical images for the `Person` then carry on with foreign key. If only **one** `Person` has **one** `ImageModel` then I would consider using a `OneToOneField`.

Comment: Yes, sure. There could even be models with ManyToMany relations to my ImageModel...

Comment: So Multiple users using the same profile picture?

Comment: No, but think of a gallery, or shared pictures. As I stated, this custom Image class could be used for much more than user profile images.